# Не отображается блок Яндекс карт на IOs и в некоторых версиях сафари на mac os

Tags: ios, yandex-maps-api

Сократили код для вызова карт до минимума, код итегрируем через HTML блок в Zero-blok на Тильде. На андроид и других устройствах отрабатывает, а на айфонах и некоторых mac с сафари карты не отображаются:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=831f87db-63c2-40d7-9323-264278280192" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
    ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        })
    });
    </script>
    
      
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
     

<div class="ymaps-layers-pane" id="map"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Похоже проблема в Тильде, так как тут в сафари код отрабатывает